# en c los bucles

Tags: c

ejemplo: El usuario tenia que ingresar dígitos que estén entre el 1-5, no me da esto, y queria saber si esta bien usar el void

```
void pedir_num(int num){

int num1;
printf("escriba un numero del 1-5");
scanf("%i",&num1);
int rango;
for ( rango=0; rango<=5; rango++)  {

    do {        
        printf("Introdusca correctamente");
} while (num1 != rango);
}

int main(){

int num;

pedir_num(&num);

return 0;
}
```

gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Que error te sale ?

Answer (score 4):

Tienes unos cuantos problemas: no usas bien los argumentos, `scanf( )` necesita punteros a los datos, las cadenas han de ir **siempre** encerradas entre comillas dobles, los cambios en tus variables de entrada son locales a la función y no son visibles desde fuera, ...

Para lo que pretendes hacer, no hay ninguna necesidad de usar un `switch( )`:

```
const char *pedir_signo( ) {
  static const char *SIGNOS[] = {
    "aries",
    "tauro",
    "geminis",
    "cancer",
    "leo",
    "virgo",
    "libra",
    "escorpio",
    "sagitario",
    "capricornio",
    "acuario",
    "piscis"
  };

  int num;

  printf( "Ingresa el numero de orden de tu signo zodiacal:\n" );
  scanf( "%i", &num );

  return SIGNOS[num - 1];
}
```

Si has de usarlo por fuerza, y no puedes devolver nada desde la función, pues tienes que realizar varios cambios también:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pedir_signo( const char **signo ) {
  int num;

  printf( "Ingresa el numero de orden de tu signo zodiacal:\n" );
  scanf( "%i", &num );

  switch( num ) {
  case 1: 
    *signo = "aries";
    break;

  case 2: 
    *signo = "tauro";
    break;

  case 3: 
    *signo = "geminis";
    break;

  case 4: 
    *signo = "cancer";
    break;

  case 5: 
    *signo = "leo";
    break;

  case 6: 
    *signo = "virgo";
    break;

  case 7: 
    *signo = "libra";
    break;

  case 8: 
    *signo = "escorpio";
    break;

  case 9: 
    *signo = "sagitario";
    break;

  case 10: 
    *signo = "capricornio";
    break;

  case 11: 
    *signo = "acuario";
    break;                                                

  case 12: 
    *signo = "piscis";
    break;
  }
}

int main( void ) {
  const char *signo;

  pedir_signo( &signo );

  printf( "Signo introducido: %s\n", signo );

  return 0;
}
```

Fíjate en el uso de variables `const`, para indicar que **no vas a modificar** los datos apuntados por el puntero. De no hacerlo así, obtendrías errores de compilación, y para evitarlos sería necesario usar memoria dinámica y realizar copias de las cadenas con los signos.

Además, el argumento de la función pasa a ser un *puntero-a-puntero*.

Comment: ¿Dónde reservas memoria para `signo` en tu segundo código?

Comment: En ningún sitio ¿ Para que ? Uso la dirección del literal de cadena, que ya se ha encargado el compilador de alojarlo en memoria. Fíjate que los punteros que utilizo son `const char *`.

Comment: Ah, sí, perdón. Me había parecido leer que en `main()` declarabas signo como `**signo`, y pasabas `signo` como parámetro a la función y entonces me faltaba el malloc para asignar memoria a `signo` (que no a `*signo`, que esa no necesitaría malloc por lo que tú dices). Pero ya he visto que me equivocaba, pues declaras `*signo`, y pasas `&signo`.